# Mineflayer: make bot only reply once

Tags: javascript

Im new to js, and mineflayer so I was wondering how I can make the bot.on('chat') run once, for say the first message in chat. This example the bot just replys to every single message sent, saying the same message back.

I dont know how I would fix this, I have tried putting it in a function so its only called then, but it seems to just like open a listener and keep saying messages even after the function is done running.

```
var bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: "localhost", 
  port: 25565,     
  username: "", 
  password: "",          
  version: "1.8.9"        
});

bot.on('chat', function(username, message) {

  if (username === bot.username) return;

  bot.chat(message);
});
```

Any method of making it only reply to the message when called on, or only running that event once could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**N.B. It is 2019; please use let/const over var in modern NodeJS environments and `=>` instead of unnamed `function`s when a bound "this" isn't used.** i.e., `const bot = mineflayer...`

The on handler runs every time the 'chat' event is fired. Using bot.once would not allow you to keep checking whether you've actually responded or not. You are new to js so I would not dive into the API for removing event listeners.

Given these constraints, let's keep it simple. You could have an external boolean flag that also allows you to easily toggle on/off as you wish at a later time during runtime by having something before `if (responded) return;` in the following code.
Your code could look something like this:

```
let responded = false;
bot.on('chat', (username, message) => {
  if (responded) return;
  if (username === bot.username) return;

  bot.chat(`Received ${message}`);
  responded = true;
  return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using any stupid functions or statements just do `bot.once('chat', (message)=>{bot.chat(message)})` or use if statements like `bot.on('chat', (username,message)=>{if(message === 'hi'){bot.chat('hi')}})`